# Handle a missing SSH connection

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

In order to connect via SSH I'm using the following code:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(IP, username=USER, password=PSW,look_for_keys=False)
```

my question is, how can I handle a missing connection?
In particular I'd like that in case the connection is not  established the code goes (maybe with a GOTO?) to another point of the code where basically I restart the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use a try and catch the exception as mentioned by
[martin-prikryl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl), such as:

```
try:
    client.connect(host="192.168.0.8",
                   username="user1",
                   password="password1234"
                   )
except AuthenticationException:
    print("Authentication failed, please verify your credentials: %s")
except SSHException as sshException:
    print("Unable to establish SSH connection: %s" % sshException)
```

For other examples of ssh exceptions you can look at https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/7495/paramiko.SSHException